# How to make a solar battery charger for more than one lithium-polymer cell?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo, solar-energy, lithium-polymer

I have at least five Lithium-polymer (not 18650) batteries taken from a laptop. The print on them is pale; it says 14.01 Wh (six cells: 6 x 14 = 84 Wh, but I split each battery now.)

They are 3840 mAh each. I would like to recharge them using a solar panel (say 10 W, 12 V). Three batteries should give me 12 V, so I think I can use three of them, but I don't know what modules to use.

The solar panel has an 8 A controller.

Please suggest modules to be used. Purpose: I want to use that to power a 12 V motor driver.

EDIT: Added picture for understanding.

Goal: create battery as in picture.

[image]

[image]

Example:

[image]

P.S. I am aware of the fire hazard.

Comment: You want us to point out which solar pannels you should by?

Comment: @schnedan - solar panel already there, batteries already there. I am looking for the module to be used. A 3S BMS module listing on ebay said - not suitable for LiFePo4 batteries or something. so looking for module recommendation.

Comment: so with "module" you are referencing a charger... well I cant tell from the ebay things I found if they can cope with a solar cell as source. So as long as they can and you do not have LiFePo's... use em. and as Audioguru said in his answer, LiPo's need propper control, otherwise you might need to call the fire department. I personally would opt to have a converter from solar cell to a storage like car battery, and to have a seperated LiPo Charger. so the Charger always can expect full power at its source

Comment: so what you want ist something like this, but bigger (more voltage & current) https://www.elecrow.com/lipo-charger-p-346.html

Comment: In all likelihood, you need to find a "Maximum power point tracking solar charge controller" suitable to your battery arrangement.  If you can't find one like that, you may be able to find one with adjustable output voltage, which you could set to the charge voltage of your lithium ion batteries and use a separate charge controller.  You need maximum power point tracking for useful solar, and lithium ion batteries must be charged by a properly designed circuit, and require overload, undervoltage and overcurrent protection as well, although those can be built into the battery cells.

Comment: They are NOT LiFePO4 cells. 14.01 Wh / 3.84 Ah = 3.65 V. That's a LiIon battery - LiPo being a subset of LiIon. Vmax is 4.2V (probably). I charge max is either 3.8A (C/1) or maybe 1.9A (C/2). A 3S LiIon BMs will protect and balance them when charging. A 3S LiIon charger will charge them.  A BMS alone is not enough - you need a proper LiIon charger.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for the comment. Please can I ask more clarity and as an answer. My cells are not LiFePo agreed, I mentioned as Lithium Polymer pulled from laptop. In between controller  as in picture and battery what is required. DO you mean 3S LiIon BMS module? confusing bit is that some videos say that panel will pull back charge from battery, and I dont know, under what conditions

Comment: @KrisSwat You said " ... . A 3S BMS module listing on ebay said - not suitable for LiFePo4 batteries or something. so looking for module recommendation...." -> suggesting that youi thought they may be LiFePO4, even though you initially said LiPo.

Comment: @KrisSwat A PV panel usually has a series diode added between panel and controller to prevent backfeed when light is low or absent. This is usually less important than people think but a good idea. The diode voltage drop slightly affects efficiency but not vastly. || For a 3S battery you want a 3S BMS and a 3S charger.

Comment: sorry, if I don't understand - "a 3S BMS and a 3S charger.". Are you suggesting 2 things? will the second pic be sufficient? I am asking because I don't want to take risk.

Comment: 1st: make sure the charger is designed for lithium polymer. Then: see how the charger's manual recomments to connect the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Your 12V solar panel will probably produce 18V when its load current is low. That would explode and cause the Lithium battery to catch on fire without a 3-cells balanced Lithium battery charger circuit to limit the voltage and current then detect a full charge and shut off.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a 3S Li-Po protection and balancing board to combine the three cells into a safe and properly working battery pack.

In addition, you will need a solar charger designed for, or configurable for, charging 3S Li-Po battery packs, preferably one with MPPT.

Adding a BMS is not enough; a BMS is not a charger. Using any old solar charger won't do; it must be able to charge a 3S Li-Po battery pack specifically.

Comment: Maybe the Li-PO cells really are the lower voltage LiFe-P04 type?